# Removing a selection from a listbox, as well as remove it from the list that provides it

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, python-3.4

How can I use the following code to delete a selection from a listbox and removing it from the list the contains it also? The selections in the listbox are dictionaries which I store in a list.

```
.................code..............................
self.frame_verDatabase = Listbox(master, selectmode = EXTENDED)
        self.frame_verDatabase.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.OnDouble)
        self.frame_verDatabase.insert(END, *Database.xoomDatabase) 
        self.frame_verDatabase.pack()

        self.frame_verDatabase.config(height = 70, width = 150)

    def OnDouble(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        selection=widget.curselection()
        value = widget.get(selection[0])
        print ("selection:", selection, ": '%s'" % value)
```

Example:
When I make a selection in the listbox, this data gets returned:

```
selection: (2,) : '{'Fecha de Entrega': '', 'Num Tel/Cel': 'test3', 'Nombre': 'test3', 'Num Orden': '3', 'Orden Creada:': ' Tuesday, June 23, 2015', 'Email': 'test3'}'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
things = [{"dictionaryItem":"value"}, {"anotherDict":"itsValue"}, 3, "foo", ["bar", "baz"]]
root = Tk()
f = Frame(root).pack()
l = Listbox(root)
b = Button(root, text = "delete selection", command = lambda: delete(l))
b.pack()
l.pack()

for i in range(5):
    l.insert(END, things[i])

def delete(listbox):

    global things
    # Delete from Listbox
    selection = l.curselection()
    l.delete(selection[0])
    # Delete from list that provided it
    value = eval(l.get(selection[0]))
    ind = things.index(value)
    del(things[ind])
    print(things)

root.mainloop()
```

Edited for clarity. Since the `listbox` in this case only included `dict` objects I simply `eval` the value that is pulled from the `listbox`, get its index inside the list object, and delete it.

Everything from the second comment up to the `print` statement can be accomplished in one line as follows:

```
del(things[things.index(eval(l.get(selection[0])))])
```

If you feel like being creative.

Comment: Why are you putting listbox as a parameter in delete?

Comment: So I can access it. I didn't use classes in this example so `l` would be undefined within `delete`. I could've used global, just how I decided to do it. In your example it wouldn't have any parameters, it would simply be accessed with `self.yourListbox`

Comment: PS: Depending on what is inside the list that provides items, you can do away with all the `try-except` stuff. If all of your items will be a `dict` as your example shows, all you need is to do `ind = things.index(eval(value))`. I've used variable data types in my example to show how it can work with anything. The point is that `get` returns a `String` so to `index` it from your list you will need to convert it to its original type.

Comment: Then all you will need is `widget.delete(selection[0])`; and then to remove the item from the list that provided it, something like `del(Database.xoomDatabase[eval(value)])`. You will need a reference to this in your function somewhere however; perhaps make it a member variable and access it with `self`.

Comment: where would del(Database.xoomDatabase[eval(value)]) go?

Comment: Inside OnDouble, anywhere. You can put it after the print, before, doesn't matter. Keep in mind that at the moment you can't access it, unless it is a global variable / you make it a member variable. Just to clarify, is xoomDatabase some type of `collection` that `del` will work on?

Comment: It's a list that stores invoices. This invoices are dictionaries with their specific info(name, tel num, date,etc.).

Comment: I've specified the wrong way of deleting to you in comments, sorry. You'll need:
`del(Database.xoomDatabase[Database.xoomDatabase.index(eval(value))])`. This will delete the index of the `dictionary` in question from your list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81347/discussion-between-maccartm-and-feners).

Comment: I keep getting:


(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-test"