# Tkinter Listbox : Botton delete the selected Items from the Listbox and JSON files

Tags: python, json, tkinter, listbox

so I have a ListBox on my Tkinter menu, the items on the Listbox are my user.json list-Dict (Code below)

The question is: How can i create a button that delete the Listbox selected items from my JSON list.

I already know the code to delete the Item from the Listbox which is: lb.delete(ANCHOR), but i searched a lot how to delete the selected listbox dicts from my JSON list/dicts which I did not find any result.Thank you for the Help.

My LISTBOX:

```
#LISTBOX

lb = Listbox(tab2, width=40, height=16)
lb.grid(row=0, column=1)
lb.insert(END, "CLIENTS")

for person in data["person"]:
    ans1 = (f"Name: {person['name']}")
    ans2 = (f" City: {person['City']}")
    ans3 = (f" Gender: {person['Gender']}")
    ans = "\n" + ans1 + "\n" + ans2 + "\n" + ans3 + "\n"
    lb.insert(END, ans)
```

MY FUNCTION AND BUTTON

```
def delt():
    lb.delete(ANCHOR)

Button(tab2, text="DEL", command=delt).grid(row=4, column=1)
```

MY JSON FILE

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "Name": "Peter",
      "City": "Montreal",
      "Gender": "Male"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Alex",
      "City": "Laval",
      "Gender": "Male"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Annie",
      "City": "Quebec",
      "Gender": "Female"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Read [removing-a-selection-from-a-listbox-as-well-as-remove-it-from-the-list-that-pro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015774/removing-a-selection-from-a-listbox-as-well-as-remove-it-from-the-list-that-pro?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in the json file, the `person` key is a list of dictionaries, therefore our main task is to convert the row selected in the listbox to a dictionary and then remove that dictionary from the `person` key and write the changes to the json file.

**user.json file**

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "Name": "Peter",
      "City": "Montreal",
      "Gender": "Male"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Alex",
      "City": "Laval",
      "Gender": "Male"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Annie",
      "City": "Quebec",
      "Gender": "Female"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import json

window = tk.Tk()

# selectmode='single' says that you can select only one row at a time in the listbox
lb = tk.Listbox(window, width=40, height=16, selectmode='single')
lb.grid(row=0, column=1)
lb.insert('end', "CLIENTS")

# open and load your user.json file
with open('user.json', 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for person in data['person']:
    ans1 = person['Name']
    ans2 = person['City']
    ans3 = person['Gender']
    ans = "\n" + "Name: " + ans1 + " \n" + "City: " + ans2 + " \n" + "Gender: " + ans3 + "\n"
    lb.insert('end', ans)

msg_label = tk.Label(window)
msg_label.grid(row=5, column=1)

def delt():
    with open('user.json', 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    # get the values that is under selection in list box
    # it returns one long string in the format you inserted the data in the list box (see above-> ans)
    row_values = lb.get(tk.ACTIVE)

    # split the results into a list of words and replace ':' in 'Name:', 'City:' and 'Gender: ' with ''
    row_values = [row_value.replace(':', '') for row_value in row_values.split()]

    # in each list box row,
    # every even index can be thought as keys of a dictionary
    keys = row_values[0::2]
    # every odd index can be thought as values of a dictionary
    values = row_values[1::2]

    # using the keys and values lists, convert the row data into a dict
    # that matches the format of data in your .json file
    row_selection = dict()
    for key, value in zip(keys, values):
        row_selection[key] = value

    # remove the entry from your user.json file
    # if that entry is found in the file
    if row_selection in data['person']:
        data['person'].remove(row_selection)

        # write changes to file
        with open('user.json', 'w') as json_file:
            data = json.dump(data, json_file)

        # delete the entry from listbox    
        lb.delete(tk.ANCHOR)

        msg_label.config(text='Row removed from file')
    else:
        msg_label.config(text='Row not found in the file')

delete_btn = tk.Button(window, text="DEL", command=delt)
delete_btn.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

I have tried to explain every line with a comment. Hope you understand my explanation. Try printing every variable in the `delt()` function to have clarity.

Comment: Thank you a lot it helped, it working now. And your explanation.are very good, helped me to understand all the "Why" behind it. Have a gread day

Comment: your code worked but now I Keep getting this weird error when i tried to press the DELT button: data['person'].remove(row_selection)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: Make sure you are using a file that has the same format of data and secondly select a row in the listbox first and then click the delete button. I have edited the above code that now supports validation messages. Check it out if it solves your problem.

Comment: Oh thanks but The problem was in the Name: "xxx", when I had a name who have an espace in it made the error when i tried to delete it from the ListBox. i fixed it with .replace(" ", ")